# How to call Oauth 1.0 API in Android?

Tags: android, web-services, oauth-1.0a

I am trying to call Context.io API from Android which is based on Oauth 1.0 Authentication.

Can you please suggest me how I can create request for Oauth1.0 standard or Please, anyone can provide me the sample code of Oauth1.0 request example on that standard.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please check my answer in following link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49607975/6299045

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [scriblejava](https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava) library to access Oauth 1.0 2-legged APIs.

In Android Studio App griddle add following dependency:

```
compile 'org.scribe:scribe:1.3.5'
```

And simply use following code:

```
    String consumerKey    = "XXXX"; //api key
    String consumerSecret = "XXXX"; //api secret
    String requestUrl = "your context.io request url";

    OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
            .provider(OAuthProvider.class)
            .apiKey(consumerKey)
            .apiSecret(consumerSecret)
            .build();

    OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, requestUrl);

    Token accessToken = new Token("", ""); //not required for context.io
    service.signRequest(accessToken, request);

    Response response = request.send();
    Log.d("OAuthTask",response.getBody());
```

Hope it helped!

Comment: how can I integrate OAuthProvider.class in provider() method?I want to integrate woocommerce api.

Comment: Hi Mrugesh. Did u get your answer ?

Comment: can you please explain about `OAuthProvider.class` ?

Comment: what is the dependency for OAuthProvider.class?